# Guice Injection with Inheritance

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

First, I'm sorry I could not get more specific wording for my title. Here is my code snippet:

```
public abstract class A {
 // dependencies
 private Client client;

 @Inject 
 public A(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
 }

 public abstract foo();

 protected void bar() {
  client.bar();  
 }
}

public class B extends A {
 ...
}

public class C extends A {
 ...
}
```

My problem is this: Neither `B` nor `C` actually care how `boo` method is implemented in `A`. `A` uses `client` only for `boo` implementation. I do NOT want to keep injecting `client` via constructors of `B` and `C`. What are my options? I think I can use `@Inject` annotation directly on the `client` field declaration instead of constructor. Is this a good approach? Are there any other recommended ways? Or Am I misunderstanding something about DI here?

Thanks in advance,
Bhargava

Comment: It's normal to use `@Inject` on fields.

Comment: I dunno, I prefer to avoid `@Inject` on fields.  It's the least testable way to inject; I prefer to keep it to the constructors, even if it adds a few constructor parameters here and there.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, that was my thought as well. But then, if we really have nice test modules that we can use to inject fake implementations, I can still use test module + argument based constructor. What I am concerned about is the scattering of injection in 2 different places (may be not that bad) and non-trivial nature of injection.

Comment: I don't see either of those things as issues worth worrying about.

Comment: Hm, I simple create different Guice Modules for testing which allows inject needed mocks. Maybe it's a little bit slower than call constructors directly but works almost the same way as it will work in real life.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, regarding your first comment, I am curious as to what is it that makes the approach least testable? Are you talking about the necessity of module injection instead of simply using the constructor?

Comment: Yes, module injection of just the constructor is what makes it less testable.

Comment: Why not just use composition? You could create an interface `interface Fooer { void foo(); }` and inject a `Fooer` into the constructor for `A`. Then you can make class `A` concrete (and `final`) and sidestep this issue altogether. Dependency injection (which is focused on composition) doesn't really play well with inheritance for exactly this reason; subclasses need to know how to construct the base class while the goal of DI is to hide construction details. Either way, `@Inject` on a abstract class's constructor is particularly misleading since Guice can't ever call it.

Comment: @AndrewMcNamee, That is a great point. As long as we have control over inhertiance vs composition, what you said makes lot of sense.

Answer (score -1):

One pattern I recently started using is for the child class to inherit the parent class (obviously), and to also inject it.  The parent class just needs a copy constructor, and also cannot be abstract:

```
class A {
  private Client client;

  @Inject
  public A(Client client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public A(A other) {
    this(other.client);
  }
}

class B extends A {
  @Inject
  public Child(A a, Others others) {
    super(a);
  }
}
```

A's dependencies stay in A, and B's dependencies stay in B.